# Move scrollbars with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-gallery

I have been creating an image gallery with jQuery, all is done. The images are placed side by side horizontally within a div whose overflow id hidden (I don't want to show scrollbars).

I have two images arrow left and arrow right within links. Now I want to do is that when I click left arrow, it should show previous image and when I click right arrow image, it should show next image. I suspect I will have to move scrollbars in the right direction when corresponding arrow image is clicked with jQuery.

How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you could do this with [`scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

```
$("#leftArrow").click(function(){
    $("#divId").scrollLeft(Math.max(0, $("#divId").scrollLeft() - 100));
});

$("#rightArrow").click(function(){
    $("#divId").scrollLeft(Math.min(1000, $("#divId").scrollLeft() + 100));
});
```

With appropriate limits instead of `0` and `1000`, and your image width instead of `100`.

---

However, looking at your example page, you have another problem.

You think that your images are being placed like this:

```
    [Visible area]        [ Overflow .... ]
.=========================._ ___ ___ ___         ___
X   |   |   |   |   |   | X |   |   |   | . . . |   |
X___|___|___|___|___|___|_X_|___|___|___|       |___|
"========================="
```

and that scrolling the visible area horizontally will make the other images become visible.

In fact, the images are being placed like this:

```
    [Visible area]        
.=========================.
X   |   |   |   |   |   | X
X___|___|___|___|___|___| X
"========================="
|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|  [ Overflow ... ]
  ...
 ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|
```

... so the horizontal scroll does no good.  (The images are actually overflowing vertically!  In fact, you can see this if you use the same code but with `scrollTop` instead of the `scrollLeft`)

The images are wrapping because they are inside a div that has an explicit width.

You can solve this by placing a second div inside your first div (the one with the `overflow:none`) that is wide enough to accommodate all of your images.

As your page is, executing

```
javascript:
$("#images")
.css("overflow", "hidden")
.wrapInner("<div style='width:1000px'>");
```

will do the trick.  Then if you execute

```
javascript:
$("#images").scrollLeft(10);
```

you will see that the horizontal scroll actually works.

Comment: @Denial: i tried your code but when i click on arrows it does not move the images, see here please: http://sarfraznawaz2005.kodingen.com/demos/jquery/image_gallery/

Comment: @Sarfraz: I've updated the post to address your actual problem.  `scrollLeft` should actually work, once you address your other problem; I'm not in denial :]

Comment: thanks it scrolls now, i start working on this now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a slightly sexier version, you can animate the scrollable area.

```
$("#left").click(function(){
    $("#scroll-holder").animate({ scrollLeft: Math.max(0, $("#scroll-holder").scrollLeft() - 250)}, 175);
});
$("#right").click(function(){
    $("#scroll-holder").animate({ scrollLeft: Math.max(1000, $("#scroll-holder").scrollLeft() + 250)}, 175);
});
```